# command substitution: /dev/stdin: Permission denied

Tags: bash, sudo

I want to read the whole stdin into variable. I don't want to spawn new processes.

From bash manual:

> The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.

It mostly works, but this `/proc/fd` stuff is easily broken by `sudo`:

```
# same user. works
[root@okdistr ~]# echo aaa | bash -c 'echo $(</dev/stdin)'
aaa

# different user. fail
[root@okdistr ~]# echo aaa | sudo -u nobody bash -c 'echo $(</dev/stdin)'
bash: /dev/stdin: Permission denied

# spawn new process. not want
[root@okdistr ~]# echo aaa | sudo -u nobody bash -c 'echo $(cat)'
aaa

# try to read from fd: silently fails
[root@okdistr ~]# echo aaa | sudo -u nobody bash -c 'echo $(<&0)'

# works, but too complex
[root@okdistr ~]# echo aaa | sudo -u nobody bash -c 'a=; while true; do rc=0; read -N1024 b || rc=$?; a=$a$b; [ $rc = 0 ] || break; done; echo "$a"'
aaa

[root@okdistr ~]#
```

Why does `$(<&0)` fail?

Comment: Hmmm, looks like there's already an accepted answer. Just saying, `/proc/$$/fd/0` would fulfill your purpose.

Comment: @AbelCheung No. /dev/stdin is a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/0` . Same permission denied

Comment: Oops, sorry that I didn't read carefully about the `sudo` requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, my suggested solution is presented below.  After this, each of the two errors that you observed are discussed.

### Suggested Solution

Bash variables cannot hold a NUL character.  Consequently, it is only possible to read an entire file into a bash variable if the file contains no such characters.  Subject to this bash limitation, the following should work for you:

```
$ echo aaa | { read -rd "" v; echo "$v"; }
aaa
```

With `read -d '' var`, bash will read stdin until a NUL character is found.  Since bash variables cannot contain NUL characters anyway, this approach does not limit you beyond the inherent limitations of bash.

The `-r` option to `read` prevents bash from interpreting backslash sequences.  Also, if you want to preserve leading and trailing whitespace, then add `IFS=` before the `read` statement.

### "try to read from fd: silently fails"

```
# echo aaa | sudo -u nobody bash -c 'echo $(<&0)'
#
```

The above silent failure happens even without sudo:

```
$ echo aaa | bash -c 'echo $(<&0)'
$
```

It even happens without creating the subshell:

```
$ echo aaa | echo $(<&0)
$
```

The problem is that `&0` is not a valid file name.  Observe:

```
$ echo aaa | cat &0
[1] 22635
bash: 0: command not found
```

In bash, `&0` is only meaningful when combined with `<` or `>`.

Let's look again at the bash documentation:

> The command substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file).

Since `cat &0` does not work, one should not expect `$(< &0)` to work either.

### "different user. fail"

This might seem like a reasonable thing to do:

```
# echo aaa | sudo -u nobody bash -c 'echo $(cat /dev/stdin)'
cat: /dev/stdin: Permission denied
```

To see why it fails, let's examine the permissions of `/dev/stdin`:

```
# echo aaa | sudo -u nobody bash -c 'ls -lH /dev/stdin'
prw------- 1 root root 0 Jul  1 15:42 /dev/stdin
```

User nobody does not have permission to access that file.  This is reasonable: one doesn't want user nobody messing with root's files.

A 'smarter' operating system might know that nobody has access to `/dev/stdin` *in this particular case* but, for security purposes, it is probably good that the operating system does not try to out-smart itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't those `/dev` links to do this. I know `sudo` will purge environment variables, but you can still pass variables through in the form of arguments since you're calling another shell anyway...

```sh
sudo -u nobody bash -c '
    a=$1; echo "$a"
' -- "$(echo aaa)"
```

...or...

```sh
echo aaa | { 
    sudo -u nobody bash -c '
        a=$1; echo "$a"
    ' -- "$(</dev/fd/0)"
}
```

Both of these print:

```
aaa
```

...to stdout...